# Redirecting a large number of URLs with htaccess or php header

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, sitemap

I have undergone a major website overhaul and now have 5,000+ incoming links from search engines and external sites, bookmark services etc that lead to dead pages or 404 errors.

A lot of the pages have corresponding "permalinks" or known replacement hierarchy/URL structure.

I've started to list the main redirects with htaccess or physical files with simply a header location reidrect which is clearly not sustainable!

What would be the best method to list all of the old link addresses and their corresponding new addresses with htaccess, php headers, mysql, sitemap file or is it better to have all broken links and wait for search engines etc to re-index my site?

Are there any implications for having a large number of redirecting files for this temporary period until links are reset?

Comment: Remember there will always be stuck links outside of the search engines with regular reindexing. I make it a policy to always (or practically always, anyway) set up a redirection regime. Assuming your content is interesting, there will always be a bookmark or a link from somewhere. Better collect their visit as well :-)

Answer (score 6):

why not to have this list in any appropriate format - a database or a flat file, and load it in 404 error handler file? And then just search for the REQUEST_URI, and use header(Location:") to redirect

.htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

404.php

```
<?PHP
if ($newurl=db_lookup($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
  header("Location: $newurl", 1, 301);
}
```

Comment: Isn't that causing 2 redirects? One to `404.php` and after that to `$newurl`?

Comment: it's internal redirect to 404, withing the same process

Answer (score 0):

Header redirects are definitely not the correct answer. If you want to preserve your SEO, you'll want to do 301 redirects. I don't know what the path structure of your site is, but this should be possible with a clever set of mod_rewrite rules. If nothing else, a slew of

```
Redirect 301 /old-path /new-path
```

generated with a script should tide you over.

There are absolutely implications for the redirects. If you're doing a meta refresh with a 0 second timeout, Google will accept that as an appropriate substitute for a real 301 redirect, but others might not. If you're not using that particular method, you're losing all your linkjuice.

Comment: Do you think this redirect directive send some other header, hehe? :)

Comment: PHP's `header()` function uses a 302 which is handled like a temporary redirect. So you should issue a `header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');` before calling `header('Location: /old-path')` to ensure using a 301 redirect.

Comment: That's what I meant; I should have been more explicit. +1

Answer (score 0):

What I recently did, was using the Rewrite module triggered by a certain pattern in the incoming URL to request a new address from a folder with a new .htaccess where I grouped all the relevant URLs. Thus I could generate, and in due time maintain, a seperate file by dumping the relevant paramteres from my database.

Allow an example:

In the .htaccess of my site root folder, I have something like this:

`RewriteRule ^resource/show/(.*)_([0-9]*)/ http://www.mysite.no/bulkredirect/dam2news/$2 [R=301,L]`

Then, in the folder `bulkredirect/dam2news`, I put a new .htaccess file with new redirects, e.g.:

`RewriteRule    1119$        http://www.mysite.no/index.php?id=843&tx_ttnews[tt_news]=2594    [R=301,L]`

Now, the key here is, of course, to make the two ID's (in this example 1119 and 2594) match, and this I did by a clever concatenated database query. You would also probably need to work out the regexps matching your situation. But the general idea is to have a seperate `.htaccess` file, both to avoid cluttering of the main file, and to ease later maintenance (might simply repeat the db query and dump it in there).